# How can I determine which of my dependencies depends on a particular package in my node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, package-lock.json

Github recently introduced a feature that notifies you about security vulnerabilities in your `package-lock.json`. I would like to resolve these issues, but the majority of packages listed here are dependencies of my dependencies, and so it is unclear which top level (listed in my `package.json`) package needs to be upgraded in order to address the issue.

I realize that I could go into my `package-lock.json`, find the package, trace it up until I get to a package in my `package.json`, but that seems unnecessarily tedious when I have dozens of packages to update. Writing a script to automate that wouldn't be too hard either, but before I undertake that effort my hope is theres either an existing tool or (ideally) npm function that will simply give me the answer.

So, riding the assumption that I can't possibly be the first person to want to do this, my question is: 
How can I determine which package in my `package.json` resulted in another particular package being listed in my `package-lock.json` without manually going through the package-lock and tracing back every package?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [npm ls `<package_name>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls).

Example output:

```
# npm ls promzard
└─┬ init-package-json@0.0.4
  └── promzard@0.1.5
```